# What is the difference between "route" and "ip route"?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, route, configuration

I tried to understand the networking tools on Linux. I am confused now about what I should use to manipulate the static routing: `route` or `ip route`?:

**route** - show / manipulate the IP routing table

**ip** - show / manipulate routing, devices, policy routing and tunnels

What is the difference between these two tools?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `iproute2` suite is set to replace the `net-tools` suite of network configuration tools. There are "synonym" commands that perform similar function in each.

While most documentation will refer you to the `route` command, you'll be ahead of the game to learn `ip route` since distributions should stop including `net-tools` at some point.

[Deprecated Linux networking commands and their replacements](http://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/)

Comment: thank you for the link clarifying all the mess with this zoo of networking tools!

Answer (score 6):

`route` is a fairly simple tool, perfect for creating static routes. It's still present in many distributions for compatibility. `ip route` is much more powerful, it has much more functionality, and can create more specialized rules.

`ip route` isn't needed to create a static route, but as it's a much more useful tool, the effort expended in learning it and its syntax is definitely time well spent.

Comment: thank you! I hope, I don't need now the "ip route" (i.e. that simple "route" will be enough)!